# How to return data from subscribe module function angular 7

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7

I am new to angular 7 and there is a problem to return data from a component function. It may not the way to ask a question because I have less understanding regarding angular 7.

Here is my component function:

> getUserStatus

```
getUserStatus(){
  this.chatService.newUserJoined().subscribe(data=>{
    this.statuses = data;
  });
  return this.statues;
}
```

The chatService get the data from service and now I just want to return the status from this function either may be the status could be true or false. I need to return the data from this function I tried but it gives me undefined.

Comment: what's your data returns.. just boolean or an object.

Comment: There is no `return` in this function anywhere. Makes sense that it returns `undefined`.  Probably the way to go would be creating a Promise or an Observable for the true o false that you want to achieve.

Comment: Why do you want to return the status from `getUserStatus()`. What's your use case?

Comment: @ganesh045 its object like this. `{onlineUsers: Array(3), status: false}` in the callback parameter `data` . I just want to return the status or complete object. the above data is shown when I console the data.

Comment: @fridoo I am using socket.io for chat applications and if the user already exists it will return true from socket server and in another case it will return false. based on that result wanted to toggle the popup.

Comment: @DanielPiñeiro I updated the code. Please check now is that possible to do like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return data directly from `subscribe`

**Why?**

Because your function is using `Observable` and `Observable` is asynchronous i.e. the data **will not** be available immediately and your function will not wait for data and will complete its execution and return `null` and it should not be the way to treat an `Observable` because you are mixing your synchronous call of function with asynchronous code.

The proper way to do this is to return `Observable` from that function and then call `subscribe` on it. You can do it like this:

```
getUserStatus() {
  return this.chatService.newUserJoined()
}
```

And in your caller function you can can do this like this

```
getUserStatus().subscribe(data=>{
    // work with data returned
  });
```

More information on Observables [here](https://angular.io/guide/observables)

Comment: yes I am using Observable in my chat service and pass the data to the component.